# Check if discrete random variables are independent

Tags: probability, random-variables

I came across this probability question while checking the homework of one of the probability courses at my uni. It's easy but still interesting for very beginner in probability.

Suppose we have two discrete random variables $X$, $Y$ which both can take two values, $0$ and $1$. Suppose we have the following information: $$ \mathbb{P}(X=0,Y=0)= \frac{1}{5} , \mathbb{P}(X=0,Y=1)=\frac{1}{6} , \mathbb{P} (X=1,Y=0)=\frac{1}{4} .$$
Check if $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Hint: $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables if $\mathbb{P}(X \cap Y)= \mathbb{P}(X) \cdot \mathbb{P}(Y)$.

Answer: In our this question $X$ and $Y$ are dependent discrete random variables.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $P(X\cap Y)$ does not make sense. What it should have said is: $X$ and $Y$ are independent variables if $$P(X=a,Y=b)=P(X=a)\cdot P(Y=b)$$ for all possible choices of $a$ and $b$ (this is trivially satisfied if at least one of $a$ and $b$ is not $0$ or $1$). Note that $P(X=a,Y=b)$ is short-hand notation for $P(\{X=a\}\cap\{Y=b\})$.

So if you suspect that $X$ and $Y$ are in fact *dependent* random variables, then you have to come up with $a$ and $b$ such that
$$
P(X=a,Y=b)\neq P(X=a)\cdot P(Y=b)
$$
and since $X$ and $Y$ only takes on two values, you're left with four possible combinations of $a$ and $b$. Now, try and find such $a$ and $b$ (note that you will have to calculate the marginal probabilities of $X$ and $Y$).